# How to extract information from an app and put into excel spreadsheet?

Tags: ipad

I have an app on my iPad that is basically a flashcard app that has questions and answers.  I want to put these questions and answers into an excel spreadsheet.  How would I extract the information out of the app?

Answer (score 2):

Unless the app has that functionality built in there is no easy way to go about this.

Apps keep all their data stored internally, giving you no way to access it unless they include an export feature or integration with iTunes Documents or something like Dropbox. You'll have to look at the documentation for the app you're using to see if it does.

The only potential solution I can think of would be to jailbreak so you have access to the iPad's internal filesystem and hope that you can find and extract the files. You would then have to either write a script or handle the conversion to XLS/CSV manually so the data can be used by Excel.

Comment: Thanks! It is jailbroken, and just like you said, I was able to extract an sql file from the application that contains the flashcards. My issue now is that I don't know how to go about converting that data into CSV.  Could you help with that?

Comment: @Aaliyah I'm afraid that's more of a programming question than an Apple question, so it's off topic here. I suggest you make a post on Stack Overflow with information about how the SQL file is structure asking for help converting it so CSV.

Comment: However the first question you would be asked on SO is what have you tried so you need to start to understand SQLlite first. Also the question will be marked as duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5776660/export-from-sqlite-to-csv-using-shell-script